# Why am I getting the wrong GPS distance calculation in my Android app?

Tags: android, gps, location, distance

While commuting to work, I am tracking my coordinates every 1 second. When I get the distance between the two points, and display it in a TextView, I am getting a much higher number than I should be. For example, a 9.5 mile route ends up displaying as somewhere in the ballpark of 14,000 miles. Below is a copy of my code:

GPS Update handler/function:

```
public void onGPSUpdate(Location location)
{
    //Get Milestone prefs
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", 0);
    Integer milestone = settings.getInt("milestone", 5);

    //Get current Speed and Distance
    speed = location.getSpeed();

    Float newDistance;
    if(oldLocation == null){
        oldLocation = new Location("Point B");
        oldLocation = location;

        newDistance = 0f;
    } else {
        newDistance = getDistanceInMiles(location, oldLocation);
    }

    // Make sure the user is actually moving and that we have an old location
    // Add new distance to total
       if(roundDecimal(convertSpeed(speed),2) > 0 && oldLocation != null){
            distance = distance + newDistance;
       }

    // Format the distance to 1 decimal
    String formattedDistance = String.format("%.1f", distance);

    setText(R.id.miles_message, formattedDistance + " ");

}
```

Calculate Miles function:

```
public float getDistanceInMiles(Location p1, Location p2){
    float[] distance1 = new float[1];

    Double latFn = p1.getLatitude();
    Double lonFn = p1.getLatitude();
    Double newLat = p2.getLatitude();
    Double newLon = p2.getLatitude();

    Location.distanceBetween(latFn,lonFn,newLat,newLon, distance1); //in meters
    float distanceInMeters = distance1[0];
    float distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137f;
    return distanceInMiles; //in miles
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabe did a great job of spotting a bug in my code. I as using `getLatitude()` for each of my coordinates instead of `getLongitude()` and `getLatitude()`. I also switched his `getDistanceInMiles` function:

```
public float getDistanceInMiles(Location p1, Location p2){
    float distanceInMeters = p1.distanceTo(p2);
    float distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137f;
    return distanceInMiles; //in miles
}
```

The second bug I found is in my first condition statement where I set the `oldLocation`. `oldLocation` is only getting set on first run causing the `getdistanceInMiles()` function to calculate the distance from your start coordinates to your current coordinates each time instead of the distance between your last coordinates and current coordinates.

Below are the corrected code snippets all together:

```
public void onGPSUpdate(Location location)
{
    //Get Milestone prefs
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", 0);
    Integer milestone = settings.getInt("milestone", 5);

    //Get current Speed and Distance
    speed = location.getSpeed();

    Float newDistance;
    if(oldLocation == null){
        oldLocation = new Location("Point B");
        oldLocation = location;

        newDistance = 0f;
    } else {
        newDistance = getDistanceInMiles(location, oldLocation);
        oldLocation = location; //Second correction, make sure to set last coordinates to current coordinates
    }

    // Make sure the user is actually moving and that we have an old location
    // Add new distance to total
       if(roundDecimal(convertSpeed(speed),2) > 0 && oldLocation != null){
            distance = distance + newDistance;
       }

        // Format the distance to 1 decimal
        String formattedDistance = String.format("%.1f", distance);

        setText(R.id.miles_message, formattedDistance + " ");

}

//First, simplified distance function to Gabe's suggestion
public float getDistanceInMiles(Location p1, Location p2){
    float distanceInMeters = p1.distanceTo(p2);
    float distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137f;
    return distanceInMiles; //in miles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code.  You're using the latitude for the longitude and latitude of each point.  Also, there's a built in location function for distance.  Try:

```
public float getDistanceInMiles(Location p1, Location p2){
    float distanceInMeters = p1.distanceTo(p2);
    float distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137f;
    return distanceInMiles; //in miles
}
```